# changing from runnable to async task

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I've got an app reading from a socket. I've tested this on a phone with API 18 on. If I try it on a phone with API 24 it throws a `NetworkOnMainThread` exception.
I've read that I need to do this in `AsyncTask` for the later API's, or I'm doing something else wrong. I'm unsure what I need to do with my code to convert it to an `AsyncTask` for the way I'm waiting for input stream data?

This is my read input stream class.

```
class receiveData extends Thread {

    private volatile boolean exit = false;
    DataInputStream in;
    byte[] fullBuffer = new byte[7];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
    int bytesCount = 0;

    public void run(){
        try {
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "in receiveData - run exception - " + e.toString());
        }
        while(!exit) {
            try {
                bytes = in.read(buffer);
                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, fullBuffer, bytesCount, bytes);
                bytesCount = bytesCount + bytes;
                if (bytesCount >= 7) {
                    h.obtainMessage(NOW_DATA_RECEIVED, bytesCount, -1, fullBuffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
                    bytesCount = 0;
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Receive Error");
                    bytesCount = 0;
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Read Error - " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopRdThread() {
        exit = true;
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "error closing socket - " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] message) {
        try {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.write(message);
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm starting it like this.

```
private receiveData rd;

// start receiver thread
rd = new receiveData();
rd.start();
```

Like I said it's working great in API 18 but won't in API 24. All the examples I've seen are for one off tasks in the background, such as downloading a picture, not threads that are left running waiting for data.

Comment: At what line are you getting the error?  I use `public void run()` often (even for API 24) with no issues. Is this simulator or a specific phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well all newest androids API's will throw exceptions when you try connect network in ui thread.

The only way is to use AsyncTask or use Handler;

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something  
  }
});
```

Note: If you want to use network and then display things on UI then you must use AsyncTask.